# Pandas / Numpy "No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'"

Tags: pandas, numpy, yahoo-finance

I'm using `yahoo_fin` and installing it automaticly installs `pandas` and `numpy`. Which is fine and my program runs smoothly. However, I go to bed wake up and run my program again this morning, and get this error..

```
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.10 from "/Users/gabekutner/Documents/GitHub/StockPortfolioWebsite/myproject_virtualenv/env/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.25.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

I've gone to the links they recommend me to go to, but I can't find any answers. The weird part is that this is not an issue when I first install these libraries. It is only later that I get it. Why is this and how do I fix it?

I've reinstalled boths `pandas` and `numpy` and then my program works, however a few hours later after leaving my computer and coming back, I get the above error.